# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier when inserting value to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have simple SQL table called test which has two column.first column is an TINYINT and second one is a type of UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

I have created simple method to insert values into "test" table using for loop and its working fine without any errors.But once i try to create string to uniqueidentifier conversion error it will roll back the transaction and delete all previous inserted values in same transaction.

This is the place where conversion happen

```
strCommand += "INSERT INTO Test(Test, Test2) VALUES(" + i.ToString() + ", '" + (i == 251 ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(12, 1) : Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) + "'); ";
```

Here is the my complete code

```
private static string TryThisPlease()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        SqlCommand command = null;
        SqlTransaction transaction = null;



        string strRet = "OK";



        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();



            //starting transaction mode
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);



            command = new SqlCommand("Test", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Transaction = transaction;



            //for (int i = 255; i < 257; i++)
            for (int i = 250; i < 255; i++)
            {
                string[] strData = new string[] { "", "3" };



                string strCommand = "";



                //strCommand += "INSERT INTO Test(Test, Test2) VALUES(" + i.ToString() + ", '" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "'); ";
                strCommand += "INSERT INTO Test(Test, Test2) VALUES(" + i.ToString() + ", '" + (i == 251 ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(12, 1) : Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) + "'); ";



                command.CommandText = strCommand;



                if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    command.Connection.Open();



                try
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception EX)
                {
                    strRet = "FAIL";



                    try
                    {



                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        strRet = "FAIL";
                    }
                }
            }



            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();



            strRet = "FAIL";
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }



        return strRet;
    }
```

Uncommenting the two lines commented and commenting out lines below,another error with same severity happens. Transactions are not rolled back in this scenario

Is there any way to prevent the transaction being rollback or did i miss something in my code ?

Comment: YOu 8really* need to fix your code. ***NEVER*** inject values into your SQL Statement, *Parametrise* them.

Comment: @Larnu this is just a sample to show the my problem.

Comment: Just because it's a sample doesn't mean you should have huge security risks in your code, Prabhath .

Answer (score 1):

if you want previous inserts to be successful, what you have to do is, create and commit the transaction inside the foreach loop, so that each row is considered separate transaction.

```cs
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

    connection.Open();

    for (int i = 250; i < 255; i++) {

        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", connection, trans)) {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            using(SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction()) {
                try {

                    strCommand = "INSERT INTO Test(Test, Test2) VALUES(" + i.ToString() + ", '" + (i == 251 ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(12, 1) : Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) + "'); ";

                    command.CommandText = strCommand;

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    //Handle Error
                    trans.Rollback();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

But, your command is prone for sql injection attacks. I would suggest you to parametrize the query as given below:

```cs
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Test(Test, Test2) VALUES(@id1,@id2)", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter(@id1, SqlDbType.Int)).Value = i;
cmd.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter(@id2, SqlDbType.Guid)).Value = (i == 251 ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(12, 1) : Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to still go with batch transaction, you can consider savepoint for the transaction. Instead of rolling back the whole transaction, you can rollback till the savepoint.[Read more on Savepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.save?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
                        command.CommandText = strCommand;
                        trans.Save($"save{i}");
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        trans.Commit();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        //Handle Error
                        trans.Rollback($"save{i}");
                        trans.Commit();
                    }
```

Comment: Hi Venkataraman R, I appreciate your comment But what i am trying to do here is a batch transaction since i have lot of records to process.

Comment: If you are doing batch transaction then if one row fails then whole transaction fails

Comment: I get your point. You can consider savepoint. I have updated my answer with savepoint information.

Comment: Hi Venkataraman R, But for the arithmetic overflow error does not fail the whole transaction

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this statement `Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(12, 1)`. The result of this statement will remove the 12th character from your generated GUID which is not a valid GUID and hence the database insertion fails.

```
Guid Format:
"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
             ^ 12th index character which will get removed from the Guid.
```

When the condition `i==251` becomes true this code `Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(12, 1)` will get executed and it will generate the error. You need to update this to produce GUID in correct format inorder to solve your issue.

Comment: But it should not rollback the transaction right? 

when i try the same thing by replacing 
strCommand += "INSERT INTO Test(Test, Test2) VALUES(" + i.ToString() + ", '" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "'); ";

it will not rollback the transaction.and will not delete previously inserted values. That is what i want.

Comment: Man, If you want to rollback the transaction, then don't create a manual exception and force the system to rollback. You can write it in the code itself like if(i==251){ transaction.Rollback(); } after the for loop starts.

Comment: Apologies OhmnioX, I think you have misunderstood my question. What I am trying to reproduce in the code sample given above is an error to make it clear to the StackOverflow community.

Comment: The question really is, I have the same code but for two different errors, transactions behave in two different ways. When it is an arithmatic overflow, transaction does not get rolled back. Conversion failures do make transaction roll back. What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I avoid that. Essentially, I would run a number of inserts in a single transaction and I would like the transactions to commit the successful ones and skipp the failed rows. This does work right now as long as I do not get conversion errors.

Comment: Oh I got it, Can you tell me at which line do you get ArithmaticOverflow Exception?

Comment: It's in the commented line. when i try to insert value grater that 255 it will  throw an error since first column is a TINYINT field.

Comment: I think the problem lies in your try catch block. can you do one thing, try rethrowing the exception in every catch statement. That will make sure exception bubble ups to outer most  catch block which will rollback the transaction ultimately.

Comment: The issue I am facing is even if I do not rollback the transaction by code, it will automatically be rolled back as soon as the code hits catch block. Again, only with conversion errors. What could be the reason?